# Trouble with Loop and Functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, loops

So i have an assignment and ive been doing it now for a few hours and am very stuck on a few parts of it. So the parts im stuck on is having to use a loop to validate information put into a prompt, and using information from an array to coincide with with a variable in another function and finally displaying all of it.

So I have everything set up but have no idea what exactly im getting wrong here if someone would mind helping point me in the right direction? Oh I should probably mention Im trying to get the second function to go with the array so when the user enters a number (1 through 4) it matches with the prices in the array.

```
function numSeats() {
        //var amountSeat=document.getElementById("price");
        var amountSeat=prompt("Enter the amount of seats you would like");
            amountSeat=parseInt(amountSeat);
                for (i=7; i<amountSeat; i++){
                    if (amountSeat<1 || amountSeat>6) {
                        alert("Check the value of " + amountSeat);
                        location.reload(true);
                    }else{
                        alert("Thank You");}
                    }

        return amountSeat;}

        function seatingChoice() {
        //var seatChoice=document.getElementById("table").innerHTML;
        var seatChoice=prompt("Enter the seat location you want.");
            seatChoice=parseInt(seatChoice);
                for (i=7; i<seatChoice; i++){
                    if (seatChoice<1 || seatChoice>4) {
                        alert("Check what you entered for " + seatChoice);
                        location.reload(true);
                    }else{
                        alert("Thank You")}
                    }

        return seatChoice;}



  var price=new Array(60, 50, 40, 30);
        var name=prompt("Please enter your name.");
            if (name==null || name=="")
                {
                    alert("You did not enter a name, try again");
                    location.reload(true);
                }
            else 
                {
                    alert("Thank You");
                }

        document.write(name + " ordered " + numSeats() + " for a total dollar amount of " + seatingChoice(
```

) );

Comment: One of the initial problems that I am seeing is that `prompt` will return the input value whereas your code is treating it as an array.

Comment: There are also no values in the real world that where `n<1` and `n>6` are both true for the same value of *n*.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you repeat the same error in both `numSeats` and `seatingChoice`;

Let's look at what you're doing with your loop

```
var amountSeat = prompt("Enter the amount of seats you would like");
for (i=7; i<amountSeat.length; i++) {/* amountSeat[i] */}
```

- `prompt` asks the client for a *String*, so `amountSeat` is a *String*.
- `amountSeat.length` is thus the number of characters in the *String*.
- You start your loop at `i = 7`, thus `amountSeat[i]` starts from the `7`th character in the `amountSeat` (assuming there are at least `7` characters in `amountSeat`)

It looks to me more like you want to get a number from the prompt;

```
// string
var amountSeat = prompt("Enter the amount of seats you would like");
// to number
amountSeat = parseInt(amountSeat, 10); // radix of 10 for base-10 input
```

Next, consider your `if`

```
if (amountSeat[i]<1 && amountSeat[i]>6) {
```

This is saying `if` *less than `1`* **AND** *more than 6*. No number can be both of these states at the same time, so it will always be `false`. It looks like you wanted to use an *OR*, `||`

```
// do your check
if (amountSeat < 1 || amountSeat > 6) { /* .. */ }
```

Finally, it looks like you want to calculate the price by some logic, which you haven't included. However, I'm sure it will be based upon `numSeats` and `seatingChoice` so you will need to keep a reference to these choices.

Comment: Wow, i stared at my code for like an hour and didnt realize I had so many simple mistakes, like the and instead of or in the IF and forgetting that the prompt comes out as string. Thanks for the help though Ill go back now and utilize your comments and see if I can make things work.

Comment: So I updated the code with some of the stuff I was missing but I have to ask one more question if its alright, I still need a way to take the information from the Array and use it in the seatChoice code.

So basically a way to take the prices from the array and have them coincide with the choice the user makes for the seats. Otherwise thanks for the help its very appreciated!